# z-index issue - positioning css3 triangle underneath menu

Tags: html, css, z-index

Hi and thanks for taking the time to look into my issue.

I am trying to implement a menu that looks [just like this](http://www.stretchshapes.net):

The main thing here is creating those triangles for either side, then positioning them underneath the menu to give it a 3d effect.

I made it work just find on the site above but I can't seem to make it work on this other project.

Here is the [site I am trying to get it to work with](http://mikelucid.com/test.php):

Setting the the `z-index: -1;` put the triangles behind all of the background images including the white bg on `body`, where in the other site setting `z-index: -1;` leave the triangles just above the body bg.

I have tried setting all the bg images to `z-index: -1;` and the triangles to `z-index: 1;` and the menu to `z-index: 2;` but still can't make any work.

Can anyone give me some better insight on how the z-index property can be used in my particular situation?

Thank you.

Comment: this might help http://css3-tutorial.com/creating-ribbons-in-css3 got this link from this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456575/3d-ribbon-corners-how-to-do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out my issue by using this answer:
stackoverflow.com/questions/8456575/3d-ribbon-corners-how-to-do

Comment: Could make the link clickable :) + the link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm having trouble figuring out what exactly it is you're looking at/want, but these elements you're working with are positioned, correct? Z-index won't work if they aren't positioned as absolute, relative, or fixed.

[W3Schools on Z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)